# Does encrypting password multiple times in different encryption middleware work?

Tags: javascript, encryption, passwords, middleware

So, this is just a random thought. if I **encrypt a password and encrypt its salt into another** **encrypt middleware**. would it strengthen the password's privacy from potential hacker, or is it just a poor attempt? please enlighten me.

```
bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err, salt) 
bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, salt, function(err, hash))
```

Comment: This probably belongs on [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/). To me, it seems that it wouldn't help that much - if it did, it would be touted as best practice and probably incorporated in a hashing algorithm already. But I can't say for sure.

Comment: it actually can cause harm because it reduces entropy of your hash.

Answer (score 4):

NO - the bcrypt output hash contains salt explicite (more [here](https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/bcrypt)). The second problem is that when you encrypt your pasword and separate result hash and its salt and encrypt salt again - then you will need to store 2 informations at the end (two end bcrypt hashes which has one entropy source - your input password) - so the better would be at the beginning just create two separate passwords and store in separate two bcrypt hash-es (their are independent so total entropy is bigger)...

[image]